# Building a custom file format with MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task, csproj, transpiler

I am working with integrating a custom file type into my C#-project which should be built into the assembly like a regular C# file (after transpiling the custom format to C# code).

I'm trying to figure out how to do this with MSBuild and a custom task, so I'm not depending on Visual Studio to be able to use my custom format.

I have played around with `Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll`, but I have yet to discover which parts to use for feeding my transpiled C# code into the `CSC` compiler along with the `.cs` files.

Additionally is there a possibility to pass in a translation table for error messages so that the `CSC` compiler will output the correct line/column numbers and file name from the original file instead of the transpiled C# code file?